# Hola estoy creando una aplicacion en android studio y tiene 3 activities y no consigo que cuando aprietas el boton se conecten las activities

Tags: android-studio

Este es el codigo que he escrito:

```
package c.example.musicoa;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tv1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);

    }

    //Metodo 1
    public void siguiente(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
    startActivity(i);

        }

     //Metodo 2
    public void siguiente2(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity3.class);
    startActivity(i);
      }
    }
```

Este es mi android manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity2"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity3"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Y me da error cuando declaro las Activities. Gracias

Comment: El manifest.xml es correcto, las clases MainActivity2 y MainActivity3 existen en el mismo directorio que MainActivity ?

Comment: Si, te refieres que si estan en la misma carpeta guardada?

Comment: Que error se muestra ?

Comment: El error que muestra es que 'c.example.musicoa.MainActivity2' no se puede asignar a 'android.app.Activity'que subraya en rojo el nombre de las activities MainActivity2 y MainActivity3 y lo mismo con la otra

Comment: el problema al parecer es en la clase, asegura que el package sea: package c.example.musicoa; en la clase.

Answer (score 1):

Deberías de llamar a los metodos de alguna forma desde la vista. Por ejemplo, para pulsarlo desde el TextView que tienes creado, podrías añadir al onCreate la llamada al metodo mediante un onCLickListener.

```
tv1.setOnClickListener(v -> siguiente(v));
```

Quedando el código:

```
TextView tv1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv1 = findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv1.setOnClickListener(v -> siguiente(v));

}

//Metodo 1
public void siguiente(View view){
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
startActivity(i);

    }

 //Metodo 2
public void siguiente2(View view){
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity3.class);
startActivity(i);
  }
}
```

En el caso de tener un botón, deberías llamarlo arriba, al igual que el TextView.

```
Button btn_siguiente;
```

Y al igual que en el metodo anterior llamarlo desde el onCreate con el setOnClickListener.

```
btn_siguiente = findViewById(R.id.btn_siguiente);
btn_siguiente.setOnClickListener(v -> siguiente(v));
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por contestar pero me dice que las expresiones Lambda no se desbloquean hasta el nivel 7

Comment: En caso de no querer actualizar a Java 8, puedes usar: 
 btn_siguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                siguiente(v);
            }
});

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente es importante asegurar que tus Actividades se encuentren debidamente registradas dentro de tu archivo AndroidManifest.xml, además de `MainActivity` debes registrar:

```
  <activity android:name=".MainActivity2">
  <activity android:name=".MainActivity3">
```

para que puedas llamar los métodos estos deben ser registrados en las vistas para que al realizar clic, estos sean llamados:

```
<Button
  ...    
    android:onClick="siguiente"
  ...
 />

<Button
  ...    
    android:onClick="siguiente2"
  ...
 />
```

Comment: Hola Elenasys muchas gracias por contestar pero tengo un problema y es que cuando declaro las activities en el android manifest me da error. Sabes donde hay que posicionarlas o cual es el error gracias.

Comment: @Jorge agrega tu AndroidManifest.xml en la pregunta y con gusto te ayudamos.

Comment: En una pregunta nueva es que acabo de descubrir esto y todavia tengo que aprender como funciona gracias

Comment: Realizalo en el [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/244496/edit) que se encuentra abajo de tu pregunta @Jorge

Comment: Muchas Gracias.